# How to define format in logging.basicConfig() using python's str.format?

Tags: python, logging

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) teaches the following syntax:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
logging.warning('is when this event was logged.')
```

I would like to express `format='%(asctime)s %(message)s'` using python str.format. How can I do it?

I tried but had was returned with `NameError`, which shows that I did not understand how `asctime` and `message` was defined. Thanks.

```
  File "~/test.py", line 163, in main
    format='{}{}'.format(asctime,message),
NameError: name 'asctime' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks something like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="{asctime} {message}", style='{')

logging.info('hello world')
```

Basically, the analogous `.format` to the `%` style interpolation string that you have above is `'{asctime} {message}'`.  Then the only thing to do is to tell the logger to use `"{"` style format strings instead of `"%"` style strings.

Note that it isn't trivial to be able to use `.format` style strings in your individual log messages -- e.g. the following does not work:

```
logging.info("hello {}", "world")
```

This is described in detail (along with work-arounds) in [Using particular formatting styles throughout your application](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-particular-formatting-styles-throughout-your-application).

The gist of it is that you can pass any object to `logging.info` -- python'll call `str` on it:

```
class LogStr:
    def __init__(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.msg = msg
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg.format(*args, **kwargs)

logging.info(LogStr("Hello {}", "world"))
```

Or, you can go through the shenanigans of defining a [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) interface compatible object (maybe via subclassing) and registering it with your logger via `logger.setLogRecordFactory(MyLogRecord)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 1000 years ago or so, I answered a similar question with "It can't be done without a whole lot of ugly surgery", someone named mgilson commented that in the Python 3.2 beta you could now do it with just `style='{'`, and I decided that was enough reason to port the project I was working on from 2.6 to 3.2. :)

Comment: @abarnert -- I have no recollection of this -- but it sounds like maybe this could be a dupe :) -- And anyway, aren't you glad you ported to python3.2 now?  :)

Comment: Thanks. Am I also correct to understand that the terms `asctime` and `message` are unique keywords of `logging.basicConfig()`?

Comment: @SunBear -- They're actually attributes on the LogRecord (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) and logging picks them off when formatting the log message.